# How to implement what-if analysis > data tables on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps

I need to implement the function Excel what-if analysis > data table on Google Sheets.

I found some tutorials about implementing the goal-seek function, but those do not help. I need the data table function specifically. I guess it is not built-in on Google Sheets, so is there any add-on that can help me implement this?